# Обработка ProgressBar

Tags: java, android

При нажатии на кнопку, растет количество очков и увеличивается прогрессБар. Доходя, например, до 30, максимальное значение становится 60, минимальное 30. - Это повышение срабатывает.
Второе - при достижении 60, минималка становится 60, максимальное - 80. А вот тут и проблема, не изменяются значения.

В чем я ошибаюсь?

Начальные значения прогрессБара.

```
    protected int exp_up = 0;
    public int getExp_up() {
        return exp_up;
    }
    public void setExp_up(int exp_up) {
        this.exp_up = exp_up;
    }
   progressBar.setMin(0);
   progressBar.setMax(30);
```

Срабатывание при нажатии на кнопку.

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void ClickMe(View v){
      setExp_up(getExp_up()+10);
      progressBar.setProgress(getExp_up());
        exp.setText(""+getExp_up());
        lvl.setText(""+getLvl_up());
          setLvl();
        }
```

Процесс обработки прогрессБара.

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void setLvl() {
        if (progressBar.getProgress() < 30) {
            setLvl_up(0);
            progressBar.setMin(0);
            progressBar.setMax(30);
        } else if (progressBar.getProgress() >= 30 || progressBar.getProgress() <= 60) {
            setLvl_up(1);
            progressBar.setMin(30);
            progressBar.setMax(60);
        } else if (progressBar.getProgress() >= 60 || progressBar.getProgress() <= 80) {
            setLvl_up(2);
            progressBar.setMin(60);
            progressBar.setMax(80);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно условие сделали

```
if (progressBar.getProgress() < 30) {
        setLvl_up(0);
        progressBar.setMin(0);
        progressBar.setMax(30);
} 
if (progressBar.getProgress() >= 30 || progressBar.getProgress() <= 60) {
        setLvl_up(1);
        progressBar.setMin(30);
        progressBar.setMax(60);
}
if (progressBar.getProgress() > 60 || progressBar.getProgress() <= 80) {
        setLvl_up(2);
        progressBar.setMin(60);
        progressBar.setMax(80);
}
```